# Can't get bidirectional data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have events and participants. Participants, which are represented as profiles can participate in events. I have a pivot table called `event_participants`.

Relationship in Profile is

```
public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'event_participants', 'event_id', 'profile_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Relationship in Event is

```
public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Profile', 'event_participants', 'event_id', 'profile_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I go about associating the participants to their respecting events by getting the event and then attaching a profile

```
$event->participants()->attach($profile['id']);
```

I can get the list of participants in an event by doing so

```
$event->participants
```

But my issue is that when I attempt to get the events of a profile that is participating in events, by doing so

```
$profile->events
```

I always get null/empty collection. Is there something that I'm missing? Thanks.

Update: my migration for the pivot table is as follows

```
Schema::create('event_participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('profile_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('profile_id')->references('id')->on('profiles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Also if I try to attach events to profiles like `$profile->events()->attach($eventId);`

I get the following error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`event_participants`, CONSTRAINT `event_participants_profile_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `event_participants` (`created_at`, `event_id`, `profile_id`, `updated_at`) values (2019-03-16 07:33:03, 1, 17, 2019-03-16 07:33:03))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you should flip the keys in the relation in the event model as such:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'event_participants', 'profile_id', 'event_id')->withTimestamps();
```

You are using the same relation in both directions.

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to.

As per laravel docs

Comment: Hello, I flipped the keys but got the following error when trying to attach profiles to events `"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`event_participants`, CONSTRAINT `event_participants_profile_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `event_participants` (`created_at`, `event_id`, `profile_id`, `updated_at`) values (2019-03-16 07:33:03, 1, 17, 2019-03-16 07:33:03))"`

Comment: Added the migration for the pivot table.

Comment: There is an issue in your relations in your DB. Try migrating without the foreign key constraints

Comment: Or use don't include `->onDelete()` at all and it will default to `NO ACTION`

Comment: Also can you please share your attach profile code?

Comment: I flipped the keys in the Profile model and it seems to have done it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Frisbetarian anytime.

Comment: w men lebnen kamen? :D

Comment: Yup :p Ahlan bel lebanese devs

Comment: ya hala ya hala :D